# pm2 deploy production setup : executing post-setup `yarn && yarn dev` bash: yarn: command not found

Tags: bash, yarnpkg, pm2

I'm trying to use `pm2 deploy production update` to serve my NextJs app on remote server.
I've have already installed `yarn` locally and also on remote server. It successfully check version to 1.22.18

Error:

```
--> Deploying to production environment
--> on host remote-server-name
  ○ hook pre-setup
  ○ running setup
  ○ cloning git@github.com**************.git
  ○ full fetch
Cloning into '/home/my_next_app/source'...
  ○ executing post-setup `yarn && yarn dev`
bash: yarn: command not found

  post-setup hook failed

Deploy failed
Deploy failed with exit code: 1

Deploy failed
Deploy failed with exit code: 1
```

ecosystem.config.file

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "my next app",
      script: "yarn",
      args: "dev",
      interpreter: "/bin/bash",
    },
  ],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: "***",
      host: remote_server,
      ref: "origin/main",
      repo: "git@github.com*********",
      path: "/home/my_next_app"
      "pre-deploy": "git fetch --all",
      "post-setup": "yarn && yarn dev",
      "post-deploy": "yarn && yarn dev",
    },
  },
};
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3001",
... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.
Problem was on server with bashrc

On server run:

```
vi .bashrc
```

Comment out code block below this comment:

```
# if not running interactively, don't do anything
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using NVM.  There is some discussion around this at https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1290.  As kaigrunert mentioned there, another approach is to move the NVM setup above the `# if not running interactively, don't do anything` line.

For example, this is the top of my .bashrc file now:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```